# the image doesn't fit in canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I draw a bitmap image into a canvas with this code:the bitmap get from user galley

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    Canvas drawCanvas;

    public CanvasView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
    }
    public void setCanvasPath(String bitmap_path) {
        BitmapFactory.Options decode_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        decode_options.inMutable = true;
        canvasBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap_path,decode_options);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (canvasBitmap != null) {
        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
        Matrix m = drawCanvas.getMatrix();
        RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, canvasBitmap.getWidth(), canvasBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, drawCanvas.getWidth(),drawCanvas.getHeight());
        m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,m , null);
    }

}
}
```

but when i draw the bitmap it get out of the canvas view,i don't want to stretch the image,i want to my canvas act like image view in android.

Comment: use Canvas.drawBitmap wuth Matrix parameter,  setup the Matrix with setRectToRect method

Comment: @pskink i edit the code again.look at that.but still doesn't work.

Comment: remove Matrix m = drawCanvas.getMatrix(); you need only `matrix` not `m`

Comment: @pskink still the image doesn't fit to canvas and just show some part of the image.

Comment: does RectF viewRect have valid values?

Comment: @pskink i just get the image width and height of my canvas in there.what are the valid values?

Comment: remove drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap); what do you need it for? and set viewRect with View's size...

Comment: @pskink you mean my custom view size?

Comment: you want the Bitmap to fill CanvasView, right?

Comment: yeah.right.but how to get the custom view width and height?

Comment: read the View docs...